# Java : No suitable MessageConvertor found when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, resttemplate

I am working on a desktop Java application and I am trying to get the RestPerson object class from the server. The model on both sides look the same, but I am getting error as shown below :

Error log :

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:8080/rest/getloggedinuser"
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class .Model.RestPerson] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:506)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:243)
    at .Controller.Controller$2.extractData(Controller.java:87)
    at .Controller.Controller$2.extractData(Controller.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:506)
    at .Controller.Controller.lambda$initialize$0(Controller.java:61)
    at .Controller.Controller$$Lambda$77/939480786.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/rest/getloggedinuser" resulted in 200 (OK)
```

In the code, I am first authenticating, and after that I am calling this method. Kindly let me know what I should do to avoid these errors. I will also post the POM.xml I have.

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
String jsessionid = rest.execute("http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check", HttpMethod.POST,
    new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getBody().write(("j_username=" + usernameField.getText() + "&j_password=" + passwordField.getText()).getBytes());
        }
    }, new ResponseExtractor<String>() {
        @Override
        public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Cookie");

            // assuming only one cookie with jsessionid as the only value
            if (cookies == null) {
                cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
            }

            String cookie = cookies.get(cookies.size() - 1);
            System.out.println("Cookie is " + cookie);
        }
    });
    // This method below gives problem.
    RestPerson restPerson = rest.getForObject(
                    "http://localhost:8080/rest/getloggedinuser", RestPerson.class);
```

Here goes the Spring configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ourpackage"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration{


    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(properties);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("messages", "org.springframework.security.messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: not really a direct answer to your problem, but: did you have a look at what is crossing the wire when you trigger the call ? Either enable logging to see this or use a proxy like http://www.membrane-soa.org/ between your application and the REST provider.

Comment: @Marged : I used a RestClient to test and I am getting back a the correct Person object. I am editing my post to include what I get from RestClient.

Comment: Spring configuration fixed, looking for how to add MessageConvertor in ApplicationConfiguration.java file mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Use below configuration in application-context.xml and you have to only autowired the resttemplate where you want to call web service.

```
<bean id="multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
    <property name="readTimeout" value="${restTemplateTimeoutInMilliseconds}" />
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory"/>
    <property name="errorHandler" ref="restaurantsErrorHandler"/>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this stuf is worked on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Darshan, I will surely try it out, but my Spring configuration is messed up : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164743/javafx-integrating-spring-framework-with-javafx-appincorrect-configuration . I have never worked with JavaFX before, so having difficult time.

Comment: Where is your <ref bean="jsonConverter" /> ??

Comment: Add at last in above configuration ` <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
             <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
           </bean>
    
   <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
 <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>`

Comment: Which version of spring-web dependency are you using, I am at 4.0.6.Release, that is why I am unable to find org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory and org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverte‌​r.

Comment: Spring version 4.0.4.RELEASE.