# How to inject services into JavaFX controllers using Dagger 2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javafx, dagger-2

JavaFX itself has some means of DI to allow binding between XML-described UIs and controllers:

```
<Pane fx:controller="foo.bar.MyController">
  <children>
    <Label fx:id="myLabel" furtherAttribute="..." />
  </children>
</Pane>
```

The Java-side looks like this:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label myLabel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // FXML-fields have been injected at this point of time:
        myLabel.setText("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

For this to work, I can not just create an instance of MyController. Instead I have to ask JavaFX to do stuff for me:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MyApp.class.getResource("/fxml/myFxmlFile.fxml"), rb);
loader.load();
MyController ctrl = (MyController) loader.getController();
```

**So far, so good**

However, if I want to use Dagger 2 to inject some non-FXML-dependencies into the constructor of this controller class, I have a problem, as I have no control over the instantiation process, if I use JavaFX.

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label myLabel;

    /*
    How do I make this work?

    private final SomeService myService;

    @Inject
    public MyController(SomeService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    */

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // FXML-fields have been injected at this point of time:
        myLabel.setText("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

There is one API that looks promising: `loader.setControllerFactory(...);` Maybe this is a good point to start with. But I do not have enough experience with these libraries to know how to approach this problem.

Comment: FXML is mostly just an XML schema that describes object graphs for JavaFX, but it can be used to describe any object.  Can you use FXML to describe your dependency and have it injected by the FXML loader instead?  Truthfully, mixing services into your view sounds like a possible violation of separation of concerns.  This would be a good place, for example, to use an Enterprise JavaBean into which your service reference can be injected while preserving the decoupling that MVC design provides.

Comment: You can always create the controller in code, and call `setController` on your `FXMLLoader`, instead of specifying it with the `fx:controller` attribute. Or, you can use a `controllerFactory`, which maps the class specified in the `fx:controller` attribute to an actual instance.

Comment: @James_D Yes, in the meantime I came to the same conclusing. Calling setController is _the_ only way, as dependencies are resolved at compile time. A reflection-based controller factory is simply not possible. However one must not specify a controller in the .fxml file to avoid conflicts. I am going to answer this myself tomorrow (maybe even add an example project to github), if nobody posts one first.

Comment: I don't know Dagger, so I may be wrong here, but the `controllerFactory` really doesn't have to be reflection-based. [Here's a Spring example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164743/javafx-integrating-spring-framework-with-javafx-appincorrect-configuration), if you know spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Map multibinding mechanism](https://dagger.dev/multibindings.html#map-multibindings) hint from @Sebastian_S  I've managed to make automatic controller binding using `Map<Class<?>, Provider<Object>>` that maps each controller to its class.

In Module collect all controllers into Map named "Controllers" with corresponding Class keys

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

    // ********************** CONTROLLERS **********************
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @Named("Controllers")
    @ClassKey(FirstController.class)
    static Object provideFirstController(DepA depA, DepB depB) {
        return new FirstController(depA, depB);
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @Named("Controllers")
    @ClassKey(SecondController.class)
    static Object provideSecondController(DepA depA, DepC depC) {
        return new SecondController(depA, depC);
    }
}
```

Then in Component, we can get an instance of this Map using its name. The value type of this map should be `Provider<Object>` because we want to get a new instance of a controller each time `FXMLLoader` needs it.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MyDiContainer {
    // ********************** CONTROLLERS **********************
    @Named("Controllers")
    Map<Class<?>, Provider<Object>> getControllers();
}
```

And finally, in your FXML loading code, you should set new ControllerFactory

```
MyDiContainer myDiContainer = DaggerMyDiContainer.create()
Map<Class<?>, Provider<Object>> controllers = myDiContainer.getControllers();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setControllerFactory(type -> controllers.get(type).get());
```

Comment: After some years with JavaFX and Dagger, this is what I consider the best practice right now. Thanks for sharing it.
I'd even simplify it further by not using `@Provides` but rather `@Binds` as I now do it [in this project](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/blob/4e2122a64fd33f6b0146d72bd4e2fa7e7df16d1c/main/ui/src/main/java/org/cryptomator/ui/preferences/PreferencesModule.java#L61-L84).

Answer (score 4):

A custom `ControllerFactory` would need to construct Controllers of certain types only known at runtime. This could look like the following:

```
T t = clazz.newInstance();
injector.inject(t);
return t;
```

This is perfectly ok for most other DI libraries like Guice, as they just have to look up dependencies for the type of `t` in their dependency graph.

Dagger 2 resolves dependencies during compile time. Its biggest features is at the same time its biggest problem: If a type is only known at runtime the compiler can not distinguish invocations of `inject(t)`. It could be `inject(Foo foo)` or `inject(Bar bar)`.

(Also this wouldn't work with final fields, as `newInstance()` invokes the default-constructor).

---

Ok no generic types. Lets look at a second approach: Get the controller instance from Dagger first and pass it to the FXMLLoader afterwards.

I used the CoffeeShop example from Dagger and modified it to construct JavaFX controllers:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = DripCoffeeModule.class)
interface CoffeeShop {
    Provider<CoffeeMakerController> coffeeMakerController();
}
```

If I get a CoffeeMakerController, all its fields are already injected, so I can easily use it in `setController(...)`:

```
CoffeeShop coffeeShop = DaggerCoffeeShop.create();
CoffeeMakerController ctrl = coffeeShop.coffeeMakerController().get();

/* ... */

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl, rb);
loader.setController(ctrl);
Parent root = loader.load();
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.show();
```

My FXML file must not contain a fx:controller attribute, as the loader would try to construct a controller, which of course stands in conflict with our Dagger-provided one.

The full example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/totalvoidness/daggerfx)

Comment: Here is an interessting example of a very lightweight DI framework: [afterburner.fx](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do something like:

```
...

  loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
     @Override
     public Object call(Class<?> type) {

        switch (type.getSimpleName()) {
           case "LoginController":
              return loginController;
           case "MainController":
              return mainController;
           default:
              return null;
        }
     }
  });

...
```

As @Sebastian_S noted, a reflection-based controller factory is not possible. However calling setController is not the only way, I actually like this setControllerFactory approach better because it doesn't break the tooling (e.g. IntelliJ's XML inspections) but having to explicitly list out all the classes is definitely a drawback.

Comment: Interesting approach. I think I'm going to fiddle around with this when I find time!

Comment: Instead of the switch-statement, we might use a lookup Map and Dagger's [Map multibinding mechanism](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html#map-multibindings)

Answer (score 0):

This is solved probably long ago for many people. I did not like the solution described here in as it relies on class names or reflection over clean design. I wrote a bit different one that looks more maintainable to my eyes.

The gist of it is to use Dagger to create the Scene that is injected into the `Stage`. Here is my Application class

```
CameraRemote context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public SimpleUI() {
    context = DaggerCameraRemote.builder().build();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    stage.setTitle("Remote Control");
    stage.setScene(context.mainFrame());
    stage.show();
}
```

I have in my Dagger 2 module the logic for loading fxml and customization of the controller i.e. injecting the SsdpClient

```
@Provides
public static Scene provideMainScene(SsdpClient ssdpClient) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(CameraModule.class.getResource("/MainFrame.fxml"));
        Parent root;
        root = loader.load();
        MainController controller = (MainController) loader.getController();
        controller.setClient(ssdpClient);
        return new Scene(root, 800, 450);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load MainFrame.fxml", e);
    }
}
```

I can split further the creation of `Parent` instance. It is not used anywhere else and I compromised.

Comment: Turns out it is important to keep reference to your controller in your Dagger 2 configuration. So I ended up returning an object that captures both controller and Scene.

This way I can refer to the controller in other places. For example event dispatcher that listens on the network can now post events to the UI...